# On the extension of Josephus rings

Tags: c

I've seen a lot of examples of Joseph's rings, and most of them are for one survivor.   I decide it would be over if half the number of people stayed.   But I had some problems running it.   For example, 40 people, the number of people who reported 9 left, the number of people decreased by 1, until the number of people is less than 20.   According to my code, the number of the output leavers is only 9 and 18, personally think that the number and length are determined by the number of 1 to 40, I may have confused something, I hope you can help me to see.
My hope is that the leavers are numbered: 9 18 27 36 5 15 25 35 6 17 29 40 12 24 38 11 26 1 16 32
Survivor number: 31 33 34 37 39 2 3 4 7 8 10 13 14 19 20 21 22 23 28 30
It would be better if we can use a single linked table, thanks!

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}LNode, * LinkList;

void Joseph(int n, int m) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    LinkList head, tail, p, q;

    head = (LinkList)malloc(sizeof(LNode));
    head->data = -1;
    head->next = NULL;

    int number = 0;

    if (n == 0 || m == 0) free(head); 
    else {
        tail = head;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            p = (LinkList)malloc(sizeof(LNode));
            p->data = i + 1;
            tail->next = p;
            p->next = head->next;
            tail = p;
            number++;
        }
        p = head->next;
        q = tail;
        i = 1;
        printf("The man who swims into the sea is  ");
        while (number > n / 2) {
            if (i == m) {
                q->next = p->next;
                printf("%d ", p->data);
                free(p);
                p = q->next;
                i = 1;
            }
            else {
                q = p;
                p = p->next;
                i++;
            }
            number--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: reduce review needs: `head = (LinkList)malloc(sizeof(LNode));` --> `head = malloc(sizeof head[0]);`.  The first obliges searching prior code for correctness.  The 2nd is easier to verify correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void josephus_ring(int num_people, int k) {
  int * people = (int * ) malloc(num_people * sizeof(int));
  int * eliminated = (int * ) malloc((num_people / 2) * sizeof(int));
  int i, j, eliminated_count = 0;

  // Initialize the array to represent the circle of people
  for (i = 0; i < num_people; i++) {
    people[i] = i + 1;
  }

  // Start from the first person
  int index = 0;

  while (num_people > (num_people / 2)) {
    // Find the person to be eliminated
    index = (index + k - 1) % num_people;

    eliminated[eliminated_count++] = people[index];

    // Shift the remaining people to fill the gap
    for (j = index; j < num_people - 1; j++) {
      people[j] = people[j + 1];
    }

    num_people--;
  }

  // Print the eliminated people
  printf("Eliminated people: ");
  for (i = 0; i < eliminated_count; i++) {
    printf("%d ", eliminated[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  // Free allocated memory
  free(people);
  free(eliminated);
}

int main() {
  int num_people = 40;
  int k = 9;

  josephus_ring(num_people, k);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the run results don't seem to be 20 people... It didn't meet my expectations, but thank you

Comment: @gaetano, `malloc((num_people / 2) * sizeof(int));` is too small an allocation when `num_people` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer by @gaetano has an error due to modifying the value of num_people. Following is solution using the Ada programming language. Fixing that problem provides 20 people not eliminated.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   procedure josephus_ring (Num_People : Natural; K : Natural) is
      type person is record
         Id         : Positive;
         Eliminated : Boolean := False;
      end record;

      type person_arr is array (Natural range 0 .. Num_People - 1) of person;

      People_Count : Natural := Num_People;

      People : person_arr;
      Index  : Natural := 0;
   begin
      -- set up the people array to represent the circle of people
      for I in People'Range loop
         People (I).Id := I + 1;
      end loop;

      -- starting from first element, find the person to be eliminated
      Index := (Index + K - 1);
      while People_Count > Num_People / 2 loop
         if not People (Index).Eliminated then
            People (Index).Eliminated := True;
            People_Count              := People_Count - 1;
         end if;
         Index := (Index + K) mod Num_People;
      end loop;

      -- print the eliminated people
      Put_Line ("Eliminated people:");
      for P of People loop
         if P.Eliminated then
            Put (Item => P.Id, Width => 3);
         end if;
      end loop;
      New_Line;

      -- print the surviving people
      Put_Line ("Surviving people:");
      for P of People loop
         if not P.Eliminated then
            Put (Item => P.Id, Width => 3);
         end if;
      end loop;
      New_Line;

   end josephus_ring;

begin
   josephus_ring (Num_People => 40, K => 9);
end Main;
```

The output of this program is:

```text
Eliminated people:
  1  2  5  6  9 10 11 14 15 18 19 20 23 24 27 28 32 33 36 37
Surviving people:
  3  4  7  8 12 13 16 17 21 22 25 26 29 30 31 34 35 38 39 40
```